# Understand and use this JSON data in iOS

Tags: ios, json, ios5, nsdictionary

---

I created a web service which returns JSON or so I think. The data returned look like this:

```
{"invoice":{"id":44,"number":42,"amount":1139.99,"checkoutStarted":true,"checkoutCompleted":true}}
```

To me, that looks like valid JSON.

Using native JSON serializer in iOS5, I take the data and capture it as a NSDictionary.

```
NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[request responseData] options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"json count: %i, key: %@, value: %@", [json count], [json allKeys], [json allValues]);
```

The output of the log is:

```
json count: 1, key: (
    invoice
), value: (
        {
        amount = "1139.99";
        checkoutCompleted = 1;
        checkoutStarted = 1;
        id = 44;
        number = 42;
    }
)
```

So, it looks to me that the JSON data has a NSString key "invoice" and its value is NSArray `({amount = ..., check...})`

So, I convert the values to NSArray:

```
NSArray *latestInvoice = [json objectForKey:@"invoice"];
```

But, when stepping through, it says that latestInvoice is not a CFArray. if I print out the values inside the array:

```
for (id data in latestInvoice) {
        NSLog(@"data is %@", data);
    }
```

The result is:

```
data is id
data is checkoutStarted
data is ..
```

I don't understand why it only return the "id" instead of "id = 44". If I set the JSON data to NSDictionary, I know the key is NSString but what is the value? Is it NSArray or something else?

This is the tutorial that I read:
[http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5](http://Json%20Tutorial)

Edit: From the answer, it seems like the "value" of the NSDictionary *json is another NSDictionary. I assume it was NSArray or NSString which is wrong. In other words, [K,V] for NSDictionary *json = [@"invoice", NSDictionary]

Comment: Is it possible that the objectForKey `invoice` is actually a string, and you need to further parse it as json?

Comment: Provide a simple `NSLog`: `NSLog(@"json: %@", json);`

Comment: It seems like the "value" of the NSDictinary *json is another NSDictionary. I assume it was either a NSString or NSArray which is where I was wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
NSArray *latestInvoice = [json objectForKey:@"invoice"];
```

In actual fact, it should be:

```
NSDictionary *latestInvoice = [json objectForKey:@"invoice"];
```

...because what you have is a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: And it's probably wise to say that with arrays you don't have a key for every value - if there are key-value pairs, it's likely to be dictionary.

Comment: Well, I thought that the value of NSDictionary *json is an NSArray but it turns out to be another NSDictionary. That's where I tripped up. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, native JSON parser, didn't even notice it was introduced.

```
NSArray *latestInvoice = [json objectForKey:@"invoice"];
```

This is actually a NSDictionary, not a NSArray. Arrays wont have keys. You seem capable from here.

Answer (score 1):

Here I think You have to take to nsdictionary like this

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: jsonURL];

NSDictionary *office = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

NSDictionary *invoice = [office objectForKey:@"invoice"];
```